# JSP can't write file

Tags: jsp, tomcat, file-permissions

I’ve got a file upload JSP that was working, but now is not.
It’s not working now after our server was replaced and software was updated (tomcat5 to tomcat6, etc.).
Here’s the code:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(savePathFile);
fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
```

The file is created with the first line, new FileOutputStream(…),  (filesize is 0), but the second line, .write, throws an exception.  The file’s owner/group is tomcat/tomcat.

So it seems tomcat should have the right permissions.
I also looked at tomcat java permission policies (catalina.policy) to see if there were the correct FilePermissions.  They were not there, so we added:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/myapp/-" {
permission java.io.FilePermission "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/myapp/photographs", "read, write";
}
```

But it didn’t make a difference.  Then I was told that tomcat was not being started with the security option enabled.

```
tomcat6.conf:SECURITY_MANAGER="false"
```

I'm not sure where else I should look.  I have a few explicit questions:

How can I see what permissions (rwx) the user tomcat actually has on this directory?

How can I verify that tomcat is or is not running with the security options enabled?

For the permission, should it read:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.home}/webapps/myapp/admin/-" {
```

since the upload.jsp file is in webapps/myapp/admin directory?

Thank you for any help,
Frank

Comment: What exception was thrown? Show us the error message.

Comment: It's an IOException from the FileOutputStream.write() call, and Exception.getMessage() is "null".

Comment: Is that a typo on your second line? FileOut should be fileOut.

Comment: it looks like this editor capitalized the first character of the line - it is fileOut - i edited the post.

Comment: Did you use fileOut.close();  ?

Comment: yup, fileOut.flush() and fileOut.close() right after the write.  It's been working for a couple years, only now with the new server and version of tomcat (6) it's not.  thanks.

Comment: I don't remember any changes between Tomcat5 and Tomcat6 that would have any effect on this code. I would try to get a better debug message. Maybe you should try the same code in a Servlet. That might shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue - it had to do with the way the multipart data was parsed. I'm not sure why that changed withe the new server, perhaps character encoding, but i changed my code and it's working.  Thanks all for you comments.

Answer (score 0):

This won't answer your question, but point in a completely different direction (architecture-wise):

It's bad practice to upload files directly into your webapplication. For several reasons:

- Your application might not be "exploded", thus living purely in a WAR file that has not been unzipped to the filesystem. Thus there'd be no directory to write to
- You will need to check for vulnerabilities. It'd be easy otherwise to upload malicious files to your server: Imagine a file `administration.jsp` to be uploaded. Tomcat will happily compile/execute it server-side (this might be exactly what you're after, but the "photograph" folder suggests that it's rather image-resources that should be stored somewhere else and served by a download servlet - you can still make the path appear as if it was served as a static resource
- On updates you'll have to remember that your webapplication probably contains different content than you once deployed - e.g. all the uploaded resources. If someone else does the update in order to troubleshoot ("I know how to upgrade a tomcat application - what could possibly go wrong?") they might inadvertently get rid of all uploaded resources.

With these changes, I'd recommend to configure an absolute path to be configured as writeable by tomcat.

Coming back to your original question, you might want to check if your new tomcat indeed runs as user tomcat that has write permissions to your directory. Also check the filesystem's capacity, the user's quota and the directory's owner and permissions

Comment: olaf - thanks for the comments, i have recently read some posts on that subject, and will look into moving the photographs upload directory out from under webapps.  I'll try to confirm the permissions, capacity and quota.  Thanks.

Comment: confirmed user is tomcat, rwx permissions, no capacity or quota issues.